# Putting together and breaking

Tags: word-usage

[image: wooden track pieces]

My little sister asked me to join the wooden track pieces (train) together,  after a while, I found that she had spread the train tracks all across the floor.

> You asked me to **put** these **together** and  you've **broken** them already?

(Not literally "broken", I want it to mean that the track is broken; all the pieces of the track are spread all over the floor and not as a complete train's track)

What is a natural way to express their two bold words? ("Put together" And "Break")

And if it is not spread all over the floor,  it's something like this:

[image: partially assembled wooden track pieces]

Answer (score 2):

There are other possible answers for this I think, but in my opinion, these two are good choices:

> **to assemble/assembling and to disassemble/disassembling**

**[assemble X](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/assemble?q=assemble)** > to fit together all the separate parts of something such as a piece of furniture or a machine:The cupboard is easy to assemble.

**[disassemble X](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/disassemble)** > to take apart a machine or structure so that it is in separate pieces
We had to completely disassemble the engine to find the problem.

**OR**

> **put them together and take them apart**

[**put X together**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/put-together)
​  > to make or prepare something by fitting or collecting parts together;
to put together a model plane/an essay/a meal

**[take X apart](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/take-apart?q=take%20apart)**
​> to separate a machine or piece of equipment into the different parts that it is made of

Hence,

> You asked me to **put these together** and you've **taken them apart** already?
>
> You asked me to **assemble these** and you've **disassembled them** already?

Or better wording, considering the context where the rails were taken apart right after assembling them:

> You asked me **to put these together** and/but you've **taken them apart** right away?

Comment: "You asked me to assemble these and you've disassembled them" is probably a bit above the reading level of the OP's "little sister"

Answer (score 0):

To my eyes, the best way to handle this is via a slight adjustment - think of it as a set, or as 'track', so:

"I asked you to put the track/set together, but it is still all broken."

I agree with your disquiet at using 'broken' when referring to the parts - they are indeed not *damaged* in any way, which is the primary meaning of broken, but it is by far the commonest word to use otherwise.

Comment: Why not “you’ve pulled it all apart?”, or “you took it apart!” Or “you’ve taken it all apart!”

Comment: @whiskeychief  That doesn't fit with the given narrative: "My little sister asked me to join ..."

Comment: So Mike,  you don't find "take it apart"?  What does it imply to you.  And do you find "break"  natural?

Comment: “Take it apart” is very natural sounding.  Apart, the opposite of together, is perfect here.

Comment: @MikeBrockington so “she took it apart” or “while I was assembling the track she was taking it apart?” — I don’t understand your question.

Comment: And @whiskeychief will you use "break" if you think of "track as a collective set of tracks pieces put together"?  And do you find "put together" natural as well?

Comment: “Why did you break it?” — yes.

Comment: @whiskeychief   I meant that you can't take something apart unless it is already joined - the context here made it clear that the track was NOT already joined.

Comment: I didn’t understand that from your question, because you said it took “a while” to realize that.    In that case I’d just say “she had scattered them (everywhere)”, or ask “why did you scatter them?” Or “why did you put them everywhere?”

Comment: “Disassemble” is used when you know they were previously assembled.   This answerer thought (as I did) that the pieces were being pulled apart after you put them together (or at the same time).

Comment: Agree with this answer — the track is “broken”, but the pieces are not broken.